# emacs color theme initialization

Tags: emacs, colors, initialization, themes

In emacs 24.3.1 I am trying to configure my default color theme. In my `.emacs` file I placed the following lines of code:

```
(require 'color-theme)                                                                      
(color-theme-initialize)                                                                    
(color-theme-hober)
```

To begin my session I open up the terminal and type `emacs`, all of the text has the right colors except the background is white and the text is black instead of the other way around (comments, keywords, and strings are the correct colors). If I perform the following:

```
M-x load-file
Load file: ~/.emacs
```

then all the colors are correct, as advertised when selecting color themes from the list after executing:

```
M-x color-theme-select
```

Note that if I quit emacs and go back to the terminal and restart emacs I have the same problem. As all my other settings in my `.emacs` file are working properly there must be some error specifically with the three lines of color-theme code above.

1. Why does it fix itself after I reload the `.emacs` file?
2. How can I fix this so that all the correct colors are loaded from the start?

Comment: When you get a little more comfortable, consider opening up color-theme.el and taking what you like and putting it in your .emacs -- then you can change everything easily to whatever you want.  Another option is to save your settings under options, and then check the .emacs file that has been saved, which may contain all of the applicable faces -- then you can change them any way you want.  You want to make sure you do not have conflicting init.el and .emacs files as the latter will override the former.

Comment: I do not believe that I have an init.el file anywhere

Comment: Some color themes are not designed to be run inside the terminal and using them there might have all the colors looking incorrect. Try it in a GUI-based Emacs to see if this is what's happening here. Terminals can only deal with 256 colors, while the GUI emacsen can handle 24 bit color.

Comment: I don't have your setup, so I cannot test, but just to have more information... could you try replacing your last line by (run-with-timer 1 nil 'color-theme-hober).  Maybe there is other stuff getting in the middle just after starting emacs; you can jump over it with a timer.

Comment: It works correctly in Aquamacs, and after adding the suggested code by @juanleon it also now works in emacs! Perhaps someone could explain why both of these work for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

From the [color-theme website](http://www.nongnu.org/color-theme/#sec5):

```
(eval-after-load "color-theme"
  '(progn
     (color-theme-initialize)
     (color-theme-hober)))
```